# How to reduce spacing in aligned equations?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, line-spacing, split

I currently have the following markup to render aligned equations:

```
\[
\begin{split}
\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} j \cdot j! &= \overbrace{(n+1)!-1}^{A(n)} + (n+1) \cdot (n+1)! \\
&= ((n+1)+1) \cdot (n+1)! - 1 \\
&= (n+2) \cdot (n+1)! - 1 \\
&= (n+2)!-1
\end{split}
\]
```

It seems like the summation is creating an awkward non-uniform space between the first and second lines:

[image]

I understand why it's happening, but is there a way to prevent this from happening and reduce the spacing between the first and second lines?

Comment: Reduce, or eliminate? Eliminate is easy but you *may* not  like the result as much as you thought you would, evening out probably involves a little more visual correction and tweaking to taste

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `\smash` to get rid of the excess space completely, and it doesn't involve any tweaking of lengths by eye.

The result may or may not be to your taste though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{split}
    \smash{\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}} j \cdot j! &= \overbrace{(n+1)!-1}^{A(n)} + (n+1) \cdot
    (n+1)! \\
    &= ((n+1)+1) \cdot (n+1)! - 1 \\
    &= (n+2) \cdot (n+1)! - 1 \\
    &= (n+2)!-1
  \end{split}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`\\` has an optional argument, so you can correct the vertical skip, writing, say, `\\[-10pt]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{split}
\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} j \cdot j! &= \overbrace{(n+1)!-1}^{A(n)} + (n+1) \cdot (n+1)! \\[-10pt]
&= ((n+1)+1) \cdot (n+1)! - 1 \\
&= (n+2) \cdot (n+1)! - 1 \\
&= (n+2)!-1
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, didn't know that. Looks great, thanks!